# Why does this linq projection not work?

Tags: c#, json, linq

The version commented out does not work for some reason ?  What I want to do is strip out the fields that I do not need in the UI.. Is this the proper way to do it ?

```
   public IQueryable<tMember> Get(int id)
    {


        var congressGroup = from m in db.tMembers
                            join mp in db.tMemPositions on m.MembersID equals mp.MembersID
                            join cmp in db.tCongressMemPositions on mp.MemPositionsID equals cmp.MemPositionsID
                            join c in db.tCongresses on cmp.CongressID equals c.CongressID
                            where c.CongressNumber == id
                            //  select new tMember { Firstname = m.Firstname, Lastname = m.Lastname };
                            select m;

        //testing
        foreach (tMember m in congressGroup)
        {


        }


        return congressGroup;
    }
```

EDIT 1: It compiles fine both ways. With just the select m it compiles and runs fine. With the other line when it gets to the foreach it says

An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The entity or complex type 'CongressDb_DevModel.tMember' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

EDIT2: the constructor is

```
   public tMember()
    {
        this.tMemMilitaries = new HashSet<tMemMilitary>();
        this.tMemOccupations = new HashSet<tMemOccupation>();
        this.tMemPositions = new HashSet<tMemPosition>();
        this.tMemRatings = new HashSet<tMemRating>();
        this.tMemVoteScores = new HashSet<tMemVoteScore>();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work", Do you get a compile error, an error message, a result you don't expect?

Comment: The code should work *if* tMember is known to have a parameterless, accessible constructor.

Comment: Is `tMember` an already defined class? If it isn't, there's no need to name an anonymous class. However, you can't return an anonymous class unless you make the return variable contain `dynamic`. So to make things easier, I'd just make a class or struct that you can return on. Or even just use `KeyValuePair` or something for firstname and lastname.

Comment: @DavidS. `tMember` is clearly the type of the first source sequence, given that `select m` works.

Comment: @Servy ah, you are right of course. Didn't think that far.

Comment: It is a database first EF template being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new type, rather than trying to reuse `tMember`.

```
public class Name
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then change the return type of the method and change the select to:

```
select new Name { Firstname = m.Firstname, Lastname = m.Lastname };
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with EF, but is there any reason just selecting a new anonymous type wouldn't work? `select new { Firstname = m.Firstname, Lastname = m.Lastname };` (rather than defining a new class just for this)

Comment: @valverij He needs to return this from the function, and since anonymous types aren't designed to be used outside of the scope that defines them, the callers cannot effectively access the properties.

Comment: that's works.. Not sure why I can't use the Entity.. or I think anonymous would be nicer since I do not have to define a separate class.. but no big deal. it works now!

Comment: @servy, right, I was thinking more from the perspective of creating new `tMember` objects and setting `Firstname` and `Lastname` from the anonymous objects. Either way works though.

Comment: @punkouter The problem is likely that `tMember` executes code in the default constructor, which the linq to EF won't be able to translate.